# Why can file-roller extract rar files in Debian 8?

Tags: debian, rar, file-roller

I have only enabled `main` component of Debian repository (Debian 8, Jessie) yet file-roller (Archive Manager) can extract a RAR compressed file.

I have the following programs installed:

```
file-roller, p7zip-full
```

but I do not have these programs on my machine, `p7zip, p7zip-rar, rar, unrar, unrar-free`.

What is the backend that file-roller is using?

Comment: It's using `unar` (from `unarchiver`) [as of v 3.6](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=646606)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting don's comment as a potential Answer:

It's using `unar` (from `unarchiver`) [as of v 3.6](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=646606)